# I accidentally clicked on zero brightness

Tags: brightness

I am using Ubuntu 18.04 (just transferred from Windows 10) and I dropped the brightness range slider to zero, now my screen is black, mouse light and all indicating lights are on just screen is black. Any solution

Comment: what is your screen model? does it have physical button's?

Comment: Nope, no buttons

Comment: 0k..I think its possible from terminal without looking at screen with a command.. need to check it.. will check and revert back..

Comment: What should I do

Comment: is it a laptop or desktop? do your keyboard have brightness keys?

Comment: It's a laptop, no keys for controlling brightness

Comment: I read another q&a someone said use F12 and F11 but they are not working for me

Comment: does your keyboard have symbols of brightness up and down?

Comment: if you are at desktop screen Windows+m then Right Arrow then DownArrow then DownArrow and Right Arrow Continuously to Increase Brightness..

Comment: Quick fix: Use a bright LED flashlight and shine from the side of screen, then look for the slider again. Found this trick from [this relevant reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxmint/comments/at8hyx/accidentally_set_screen_brightness_to_zero_screen/).

Comment: Thanks man it works

Comment: @Y.K Dear OP, feel free to [self-answer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) this question to explain what exactly worked for you instead of a comment. You can accept your own answer immediately since this question is more than two days old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just <kbd>Fn</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd> should work for you if you are using a laptop.

If you dont have a <kbd>Fn</kbd> on your keyboard, than you can use a bright light and take it near your screen ( I can only say about 18.04), the text will become visible.

This problem can not happen in 20.04 or above versions.

Answer (score 0):

Use the brightness settings on monitor. I was able to resolve it this way.

Answer (score 0):

The brightness control *should* just be controlling the backlight.  Which means the image will still be on screen, it will just be nearly invisible because it's not being lit and there's no reflector behind the polarising layers like on much older LCDs.  If you shine a bright light on it at the right angle you should be able to see well enough just to make out controls on the screen.